# Converting script for replacing layers of MXDs into tool?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I have a script that runs correctly form the command prompt. But when I try to get user input for folders and an MXD, it doesn't run.

The script is as below.

How can I convert this into a working tool?

```py
path_orig = GetParameterAsText(0)
path_copy = GetParameterAsText(1)
arcpy.env.workspace = path_orig
for mapDoc in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(path_orig + mapDoc)
    mxd.saveACopy(path_copy + mapDoc)


arcpy.env.workspace = path_copy


updatedMxd = GetParameterAsText(2)
#arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"E:\Trials\Python_trials\Automate_map_try\layers_update\layers_update.mxd")


for mapDoc in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print mapDoc
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(path_copy + mapDoc)
    for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
        for lyr_o in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"",df):
            for lyr_u in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(updatedMxd,""):
                if lyr_o.name == lyr_u.name:
                    arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df,lyr_o,lyr_u,False)
    mxd.save()
    pdf_name = mapDoc[:-4] + ".pdf"
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd,pdf_name)
    print pdf_name
    del mxd
```

Comment: What benefit would you get out of making this a tool?

Comment: Please post any errors you get when you attempt to run your tool, and explain how you setup the tool, defined the attributes, etc. Did you make it a Script tool or Python Toolbox?

Comment: What do you mean “it doesn’t run”?   How are you trying to run it?  Using a script tool?   If so, post the config of the script tool (particularly the parameters).   What happens that you don’t expect?   What doesn’t happen that you do expect?

Comment: Try do add on.sep when naming destination mxd.

Comment: The script is supposed to copy all mxd files from a folder #1 that user selects into another folder #2 supplied by user. Then it refers to an mxd which has corrected layers. It takes these layers and replaces the layers on the mxds on the folder #2. The script runs correctly from Python window in ArcMap. But on converting to a tool (script to tool) it doesn't copy the mxds to folder #2 from folder#1. So I get the error: gp.getIDMessage(89004, "Invalid MXD filename" . I'm missing something when I convert it to tool. Thanks everyone.

Comment: you have to actually create a tool to run it as one. In the Catalog window, ArcToolbox window, or ArcCatalog, right-click either the toolbox or one of its toolsets and click Add > Script. The Add Script dialog box opens. And then you have to map the parameters that you want to get from the user. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/a-quick-tour-of-creating-script-tools.htm

Answer (score 0):

@user143232 assuming you are running a script tool which it sounds like you are. Once you get your script to work in the python window you need to very carefully design the front end. I just had the same problem. Make sure you order them in the front end the with the same reference number in the script. Make sure the data type is the same.

Comment: The script is supposed to copy all mxd files from a folder #1 that user selects into another folder #2 supplied by user. Then it refers to an mxd which has corrected layers. It takes these layers and replaces the layers on the mxds on the folder #2. The script runs correctly from Python window in ArcMap. But on converting to a tool (script to tool) it doesn't copy the mxds to folder #2 from folder#1.  So I get the error that mxd name is invalid. I have given the correct parameters in the tool properties. Thanks everyone.

Comment: What is the third parameter? Are you allowing them to change the name of the file as well? What happens when you remove specifying the workspace and just reference the variables for the GDBs? Do the print statements give the entire correct file or are there missing the slashes between the GDB and the file name?

Comment: Third parameter (user input) is an mxd which has the correct layers. The script compares layer names in the  incorrect mxd and the correct mxd and replaces old layers with new. Workspace is not gdb  but a folder. The print statement gives only the filename eg. Test1.mxd.  What I don't understand is it works as it should from Python window when I specify 'folder #1', 'folder#2' and 'xyz.mxd' but not when run as tool when these 3 are user inputs. So I'm missing something when I convert it to tool.